# UIAlertController weird behaviour

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode9, uialertcontroller

I am facing a weird issue with UIAlertController.

1. On approval/rejection of a  ticket, an alert is presented like below

When alert first appears
[image]

2. If the screen gets locked on this page and we reopen the phone, then because of re-auth everytime app becomes active, we see the following screen.

when auth screen is presented over alert
[image]

3. If the pin is put now, and app opens, the alert control occupies a buggy position at the top like this.

when auth is done and alert screen appears
[image]

This is mainly because the auth screen was presented over alert control and everytime another control is presented over alert, this same bug re-appears.

Comment: Maybe you mess with the view controller hierarchy. Who presents the UIAlertController and who presents the auth screen?

Comment: AlertControl is presented by this first controller with Verify and reject button and auth screen is presented by the topViewController when app becomes active or comes to foreground from background.In this particular case, alertController becomes the topViewController to present the auth screen.